# Grid texture in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

How can I make a grid shader from the following picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "that looks like the following picture"? Here Anton Neveselov has made a node organization that could help you: Download the file,  append the Grid file that you'll find in the NodeTree folder. Then in your Shade Editor press shift A and search for Grid, plug it in the Principled. Play with the parameters to build a grid. To change the colors, select the node and press tab, you'll have access to a Brick Texture node, change the colors. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsZoJBeAWGc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a brick texture. Set "Offset" to 0. Set "Bias" to 1. Set the height and the width to the same value. Select the colors by "Color2" and "Mortar". Use "Scale" to Scale.

[image]

Comment: The grid is warped if the mesh is unwrapped in a non-square shape, would be better if there's a universal solution.

Comment: This is just a texture which is universal. The wrapping is depends on the mapping like at any other textures.